# What exactly is History?

Tags: discussion, questions, on-topic

I have asked a question [here](https://hsm.stackexchange.com/questions/5295/what-do-we-mean-when-we-say-something-exists-in-physics), and was put on-hold.

In that question, I would like the clarification of what the living physicists said. but it seems to me that it "the living is no history" on this site.

Nevertheless, I wonder if I can ask further about some "recent historical facts" here on this site, such as "which living physicists openly support many-world interpretations? and their reasons?"

So what exactly "history" means here on this site? Facts that must have occurred 100 years ago?

Answer (score 2):

Your question was not put on hold because it was asking about living persons, or events that occurred less than 100 years ago. These are not criteria that are used on this site to determine whether questions are on-topic. Your question was closed for the following reasons:

1. Most importantly, your question is not historical in nature, at least now in its current form. You asked what people (physicists) mean(t?) when speaking about the existence of certain objects. That means that you're asking about the philosophical implications of something "existing", in the sense that physicists use the word. That is an essentially philosophical question, namely about the philosophical views of physicists. The question might still be on-topic on physics.SE as well, since it is asking about the philosophical views of *physicists*, but I doubt it.
2. Your question seems to be asking for opinions on what some people "mean" when they say something: Questions that seek answers based on opinions are discouraged on this site. Furthermore, that is a kind of ill-defined and broad type of question.

Both of these reasons for closure of the question could be fixed by a thorough edit. If you are really interested in the historical aspects of the question, please edit your question to reflect this more clearly. But be very careful to clearly distinguish your question from a *philosophical* one.

Right now, it seems to me like your main interest is actually in the philosophical aspect of the question. If this is indeed the case, feel free to flag your own question and leave a custom message for the moderators, asking for the post to be migrated.